# How to Calculate Risk of Ruin

Tags: risk

I'm reading a book titled "A Trader's Money Management System" and it discusses risk of ruin(ROR) tables. It says that you can have a zero probability of ROR with a payoff ratio of 2 to 1 and a win rate of 60%.

- My understanding is that the concept of ROR originated in gambling, but is it applicable to trading and more importantly, does it work in real world trading?
- The book says a zero percent probability of ROR means that ruin is extremely unlikely, but not impossible. Doesn't that go against the definition of a zero percent probability?
- How do you calculate ROR? The book only includes a sample table. I googled it and this came up.

  `((1 - Edge)/(1 + Edge)) ^ Capital_Units`

  How do you fit the payoff ratio and the win rate into the edge?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to estimate the probability of drawdown / ruin?](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/395/how-to-estimate-the-probability-of-drawdown-ruin)

Comment: Hi Tom, welcome to quant.SE. I could be wrong, but I have never heard of professional quants using such oversimplified "money management" techniques. I believe your question is off topic.

Comment: Discussion of why this question was closed on [meta](http://meta.quant.stackexchange.com/q/204/1106).